# Get all numbers within a range (12300 > 12400)

Tags: c#, numbers, range

Trying to find a way to do actions on each number within a range in `C#`. Let's say `12300` to `12400`.

Tried:

```
IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(12300, 12400);
```

But that just gives me a list that is `12400` numbers long starting at `12300`.

Comment: What kind of action do you want to perform on the numbers? If you have a list of the wanted numbers, you can simply iterate over them and do what you want with them, is that not what you'd like?

Comment: Also, the second parameter of `Enumerable.Range` is `Count` and not `End`, so if you want `12300-12400`, you have to write `Enumerable.Range(12300, 100);`

Answer (score 6):

Well you need to do the math for the second parameter which is the count:

```
int startNumber = 12300;
int endNumber = 12400;
int count = endNumber - startNumber + 1; // +1 if you want to include the end
var range = Enumerable.Range(startNumber, count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also create your own range-producing method if you need something special, like defining the step.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> RangeFromTo(int from, int toExclusive, int step)
{
    for (int i = from; i < toExclusive; i += step) yield return i;
}
```

Usage example:

```
IEnumerable<int> numbers = RangeFromTo(12300, 12400, 1);
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", numbers));
```